# Autogenerate Alphanumeric ID in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I need a help. i want to auto generate alphanumeric ID example A/001/2016 where 001 should be increment by 1 and 2016 represent year using vb 2010
i want like A/001/2016, A/002/2016, A/003/2016

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub autogenerate_ID()
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = " server = localhost; user id = root; password=; database = birth_and_death "
    Command.Connection = MySqlConnection
    mysqlconnection.Open()
    Dim sqlquery = "select Max(Death_ID) from decease "
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim d As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")
    value = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        value = "D/001/1990"
    End If
    value = value.Substring(3)
    Int32.TryParse(value, ID)
    ID = ID + 1
    value = "D/" + ID.ToString("D3") + "/" + d
    ' value = "A/" + Convert.ToString(ID) + "/" + d
    TxtDeathID.Text = value


    command.Dispose()
    mysqlconnection.Close()
    mysqlconnection.Dispose()



End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend that you transfer this logic to the database.  The general idea would be to have a numeric autoincrementing primary key, and a date created field.  The A is a constant, so that doesn't matter.  You can get the year from the date.  That leaves the middle part.  Different database engines have different ways to get the nth record.  Use the one that's appropriate for yours.    Whether you generate this on every select query, or use a database trigger to store the value is your decision.  Finally, make sure you have a plan for the thousandth record.

Comment: there is little good that usually comes from such keys.  you can use SQL CONCAT to glue 3 bits of data together as if there was such a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 If IsDBNull(Command.ExecuteScalar) = False Then

            Dim t() As String = Split_Serie(Command.ExecuteScalar)
            Value = "A/" & Format(t(1) + 1, "000") + "/" & Year(Now.Date)

        Else

            value = "D/001/1990"
        End If
```

and you must create a function that split your cod as :

```
  Public Function Split_Serie(num As String) As String()
        Dim t() As String
        t = Split(num, "/")
        'Part1 = t(0)
        'Part2 = t(1)
        'Part2 = t(3)
        Return t
    End Function
```

Comment: Good iam glad to  hear that please mark answer as solved and vote up  thanks also